# Can I create an UNIQUE WHERE index?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, unique

A combination of two integer columns `(a, b)` is known to be unique if `b = 1`. The only other value b could assume is 0.

I would like to express this by a UNIQUE constraint, similar to

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    a INTEGER NOT NULL,
    b INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT u UNIQUE (a,b) WHERE b=0
)
```

However, according to the syntax charts, SQLite does not seem to have a feature that would allow me to specify the WHERE part. Is there any other way I could use?

The `b = 1` condition is rare in data but very commonly used in queries, so I would definitely want to add indexes using it.

Answer (score 0):

I've done more research, but found nothing.

The best way I can think of is:

- Create an index for b=1
- Add a CHECK NOT EXISTS constraint rather than a UNIQUE

The index can be used by the constraint and should at least prevent a full table scan (needs to be verified by EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN).